# No matching function for getline

Tags: c++, getline

This program worked when I just wanted to read in characters before blankspace by using:'`cin >> buffer`. However, I wanted to read everything the user typed in, including whitespace. So, I changed from using ">>" to a getline call. I seem to be passing in the right parameters and I have done #include  and #include . The error messages when I compile are:

> Driver.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char* const*)’:
>   Driver.cpp:49:44: error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘getline(std::istream&, char [1024])’
>                            getline(cin, buffer);
>                                               ^ Driver.cpp:49:44: note: candidates are: In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:4:0,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/cwchar:44,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/ios:38,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/ostream:38,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/iostream:39,
>                    from Driver.cpp:1: /usr/include/sys/stdio.h:37:9: note: ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)  ssize_t _EXFUN(getline,
>   (char **, size_t *, FILE *));
>            ^ /usr/include/sys/stdio.h:37:9: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided In file included from
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/string:52:0,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/ios:42,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/ostream:38,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/iostream:39,
>                    from Driver.cpp:1: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:2793:5:
>   note: template
>   std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&
>   std::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&,
>   std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
>        getline(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is,
>        ^
>
> ```
>  ^ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.tcc:1068:5:
> ```
>
> note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   Driver.cpp:49:44: note:   mismatched types ‘std::basic_string<_CharT,
>   _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘char [1024]’
>                            getline(cin, buffer);
>                                               ^ Makefile:24: recipe for target 'Driver.o' failed make: *** [Driver.o] Error 1

Here is the code with stuff removed that weren't part of this case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <getopt.h>
#include "Driver.hpp"
#include "SymTab.hpp"

using namespace std;

#ifdef NULL
#undef NULL
#define NULL 0
#endif

ostream & operator << (ostream & stream, const Student & stu) {
        return stream << "name:  " << stu.name
                << " with studentnum:  " << stu.studentnum;
}

int main (int argc, char * const * argv) {
        char buffer[BUFSIZ];
        char command;
        long number;
        char option;

        while ((option = getopt (argc, argv, "x")) != EOF) {

        switch (option) {
                case 'x': SymTab<Student>::Set_Debug_On ();
                        break;
                }       
        }

        SymTab<Student> ST;
        ST.Write (cout << "Initial Symbol Table:\n" );

        while (cin) {
                command = NULL;         // reset command each time in loop
                cout << "Please enter a command ((i)nsert, "
                        << "(l)ookup, (r)emove, (w)rite):  ";
                cin >> command;

                switch (command) {

                case 'i': {
                        cout << "Please enter student name to insert:  ";
                        getline(cin, buffer);

                        cout << "Please enter student number:  ";
                        cin >> number;

                        Student stu (buffer, number);

                        // create student and place in symbol table
                        ST.Insert (stu);
                        break;
                }

        }

        ST.Write (cout << "\nFinal Symbol Table:\n");
}
```

This is my first post, so let me know if  screwed up my formatting, and if any more information is needed to help me. Thanks!

Comment: `std::getline` is for `std::string`, which you should be using automatically, but what worries me more is your whole `NULL` spiel. That part is very bad. Include `cstddef` or other specific headers (like `cstdio`) and `NULL` will come as something that evaluates to 0.

Comment: @ghost Ensuring that `NULL` evaluates to 0 in C++ is not as bad as you make it sound. Yes, the standard library headers will take care of it. But it is common to include a (poorly-written) C header that defines `NULL` in a way that is undesirable. Of course, you could solve everything by using `nullptr`.

Comment: Ok, so I included cstdlib, and now don't have to define NULL.
But on the topic of the getline, why should I be automatically prefacing the getline with stdd::?

Comment: @user3750325 `#define NULL 0` is not the problem. The problem is that you are using it.

Comment: @user3750325, I messed up and was thinking of `cstddef`, but it's already required to be in `cstdio`, which you include.

Comment: Also `command = NULL` is not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: You don't **have** to preface with `std::`, since you're doing the `using namespace std` thing that all textbooks recommend for beginners (and that no intermediate textbooks ever seem to revisit).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All overloads of `std::getline()` take a `(basic) istream` and a `string`. To solve the problem, change `char buffer []` to `std::string buffer` and remember to `#include <string>`.

Comment: while the solution is ok, note that there is a member function [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

Comment: That fixed the problem! However, now, all lines dealing with "Student" are giving errors. (It's been a couple of quarters since I've had to deal with namespace).